# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value as int

Tags: sql

Morning,
Can anyone tell me where I should convert the below shown error to make the query run?  I am really struggling to understand how this could be resolved, please help.

Thanks

```
SELECT ORDERS.CDRS_ORDER_ID, TERMINAL_NAME, ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID, ORDERS.SUPPLIER_NUMBER,  SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.NAME AS SUPPLIER_PRODUCT_NAME,
SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NUMBER AS SUPPLIER_PRODUCT_NUMBER, ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER, CUSTOMER.NAME AS CUSTOMER_NAME,


FOLIO_HISTORY.FOLIO_NUMBER AS FOLIO_NUMBER, MOVEMENT_NUMBER AS ORDER_MOVEMENT_NUMBER, ORDERED_QUANTITY, 
NET_QUANTITY, FORMAT(FOLIO_HISTORY.OPEN_DATE ,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS FOLIO_OPEN_DATE, 

FORMAT(FOLIO_HISTORY.CLOSE_DATE ,'yyyy-MM-dd') AS FOLIO_CLOSE_DATE,
STATUS,  FORMAT(TERM_START_LOAD_TIME ,'HH') as TERM_START_LOAD_TIME, 
FORMAT(TERM_END_LOAD_TIME ,'HH') as TERM_END_LOAD_TIME FROM ORDERS 

inner JOIN SUPPLIER_PRODUCT ON ORDERS.SUPPLIER_NUMBER = SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.supplier_number 
inner JOIN TERMINAL_OWNER ON ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID = TERMINAL_OWNER.TERMINAL_ID
inner JOIN FOLIO_HISTORY ON ORDERS.FOLIO_NUMBER = FOLIO_HISTORY.FOLIO_NUMBER and FOLIO_HISTORY.Terminal_ID = ORDERS.LOADING_TERMINAL_ID
inner JOIN ORDER_LOADED ON ORDERS.CDRS_ORDER_ID = ORDER_LOADED.CDRS_ORDER_ID and ORDER_LOADED .PRODUCT_NUMBER=SUPPLIER_PRODUCT.PRODUCT_NUMBER
inner JOIN CUSTOMER ON ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_NUMBER and ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.NAME
```

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Sorry, thought I posted. Using SQL 2012 - the error is (1 row(s) affected)
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'AIR NAMIBIA' to data type int
This happens on the last join where I want to import the name field from the customer table.

Comment: @ArriBenson ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.NAME how name and number join is possible

Comment: @ArriBenson you should provide sample data and output because it seems you tried to join two different data type column

Comment: Error is self explanatory, what you want us to do?

Comment: Could you please explain why you need this condition (**ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.NAME**) ?

Comment: The ORDERS table contains the customer_number and the CUSTOMER table contains the NAME, I want the query to display both.  I will gladly paste another screenshot here if someone tells me how to.

Comment: @ArriBenson Why you are not using Customer Number in the join instead of Customer Name ? Because customer table contains the Customer Number

Comment: I have done that but the result duplicates everything.  Trying to work out on this forum how to add another screenshot of the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are joining on the wrong column in the last join. Order.CustId = Name?

```
  and ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.NAME
```

Comment: I use and ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CUSTOMER.NUMBER it then duplicates the rows.

Comment: well that is a different problem my friend, this one is answered. One of the other joins might also be faulty. We would need to see a table diagram for that.

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Can't guess without knowledge of the schema. But i would go at it by removing each join with its columns from the select statement and then  at one point the duplication will disappear, then you will know which join is not restrictive enough. Unfortunately I can't run this so the debugging is up to you. Please mark this an answer as it is an answer to your initial question. :)